# Converting my Objective-C codes to Swift code

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an existing App that was constructed using Objective-C.

My question is. How can I convert my App to use Swift code or do I have to recreate my App using Swift code?

Comment: Apple has provide very good document on this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0

Comment: Thanks for this. Now I know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Giant project Objective C to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942575/how-to-convert-giant-project-objective-c-to-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just convert your code to Swift. You would have to rewrite it.

Keep in mind that you can use both Swift and Objective-C together in the same project.

[Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: not to mention the paradigm shift from going from Objective-c to Swift.